# Correcting effect of solar elevation angle in tagged areas for Landsat 8 L1T images using ENVI

Tags: envi, digital-image-processing

Someone said the L1T images did not correct the effect of solar elevation angle.

I want to know how can I get the parameters for doing such correction in ENVI?